# Magento 1.9 :- Add to Cart Helper - not working

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, helper

I've been trying to fix a problem on an inherited Magento 1.9.1 site - the problem is coming from a custom category page I think.

The template is using the Add to Cart Helper - in what appears to be the same way as the working product list template.

On this page: http://www.trevorsorbie.com/shop/ranges.html, if you click the Add to Cart button on any product nothing is added to cart. If you log in to your account and click that button it does add to cart..

But this is working on this page: http://www.trevorsorbie.com/shop/products.html

On the **ranges.html** page I've used:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm add-to-cart-alt" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product)?>" title="Add Product to Cart">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    <span class="sr-only">Buy</span>
</a>
```

Any information or pointing me at reading material to fix this will be much appreciated!

Comment: So, what exactly is your requirement? Do you want http://www.trevorsorbie.com/shop/products.html link act like the above one?

Comment: Do you want to hide add to cart if customer is not logged in?

Comment: If you click the Cart button on any product http://www.trevorsorbie.com/shop/ranges.html nothing is added to cart. If you log in to your account and click that button it does add to cart. I'm trying to work out why it is not working on that page.

Comment: It's not in helper, it could be in phtml files. Follow the link I given in answer, check the addtocart.phtml file

Comment: Its using this add to cart button - not coming from addtocart.phtml I think <a class="btn btn-sm add-to-cart-alt" href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product)?>" title="Add Product to Cart">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
                    <span class="sr-only">Buy</span>
                </a>

Comment: Did you check the file app\design\frontend\default\sagsupplies\template\catalog\product\list.phtml & app\design\frontend\default\sagsupplies\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml ?

Comment: I've checked both. However - the list.phtml is working fine. Its just a custom template which isn't working. It uses the same add to cart code as list.phtml - but the link it produces doesn't add a product to the cart.

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this? I have the same problem as your's.

Comment: Afraid I didn't. No longer working on the project so not sure If they sorted it. If I remember correctly - the url being generated by the Add to Cart helper was only successfully adding the item to the cart when a user was logged in. Is your problem similar?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide Add-to-Cart button for not logged-in customers, then following link might help you:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731127/how-to-show-add-to-cart-after-login-only-in-every-page-with-magento

Comment: I would like it to show - I just can't work out why it is not adding a product to the cart unless you are logged in.